# Using Antlr4 to generate search queries for Elastic Search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, solr, antlr4

Does anyone use Antlr4 to generate queries for Elastic Search? I have a website where a user can enter a search term. Some search terms can have wildcards, others not. We are currently using Solr, and we have an Antlr grammar for Solr. However, the search query strings for Elastic Search are different from Solr, so I am developing a new Grammar for Elastic Search.

I was just wondering if anyone has any experience in this, and if they might be able to guide me.